# removing duplicates in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I tried out the following code in java to remove duplicates from a linked list

```
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
    LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr1=head;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr2=head.next;
    if(head==null)
        return null;
    if(head.next==null)
        return head;
    while(ptr2!=null){
        if(ptr1.data==ptr2.data){
            ptr2=ptr2.next;
        }else{
            ptr1.next=ptr2;
            ptr1=ptr2;
            ptr2=ptr2.next;
        }
    }
    ptr1.next=ptr2;
    return head;
}
```

which takes the head of the linked list as input then after removing duplicates from it returns the head.

if we take the following sample input for a linked list

```
281 386 386 957 1022 1216 1232 1364 1428 1428 1428 1428 1501 1953
```

it's not removing duplicates as expected

I tried debugging it in vscode and was amazed to see that `ptr1.data == ptr2.data` evaluates to `false` when ptr1 is at 386 and ptr2 is at the 386 after the first 386 of the input
I also tried a getter for LinkedListNode even then
`ptr1.getData()==ptr2.getData()` was coming out false

is there some concept related to memory allocation I'm not getting involving heaps or something?

if you're curious about the `LinkedListNode` class
and the function used to create the linked list here they are:

```
public class LinkedListNode<T> {
T data;
LinkedListNode<T> next;
LinkedListNode (T data){
    this.data=data;
}
T getData(){
    return this.data;
}
}
```

and

```
static LinkedListNode<Integer> takeinput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data = sc.nextInt();
    LinkedListNode<Integer> head = new LinkedListNode<Integer>(data);
    LinkedListNode<Integer> tail = head;
    data=sc.nextInt();
    while(data!=-1){
        LinkedListNode<Integer> newNode = new LinkedListNode<Integer>(data);
        if(head.next==null){
            head.next=newNode;
            tail=newNode;
        }else{
            tail.next=newNode;
            tail= newNode;
        }
        data=sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.close();
    return head;   
}
```

input:281 386 386 957 1022 1216 1232 1364 1428 1428 1428 1428 1501 1953 -1
it stops to take input after -1 is entered and returns the head of the generated linkedlist

Comment: You are aware of the differences between `==` and `equals()` in Java? `==` tests for *identity*, and your duplicates may be *equal*, but they are never *identical* – as your program points out clearly.

Comment: The simplest way to remove duplicates is to put everything into a set and then put this set into an LinkedList.

Comment: thank you @tquadrat that was the issue now its working fine,I had forgotten about the Integer object part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)

Comment: why is your data is of type T? If its all numbers that's stored in Linked List, why don't you declare it as integer? That should solve your == problem. This of course looks like an interview question, so you can very well work with numbers. Just like others pointed out, you should defenitely know the difference between == and equals().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This update is too late but it does not have NPE:

```
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
        return head;

    LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr1 = head;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr2 = head.next;

    while (ptr2 != null) {
        while(ptr1.data.equals(ptr2.data)) {
            ptr2 = ptr2.next;
            ptr1.next = ptr2;
        }
        ptr1.next = ptr2;
        ptr1 = ptr2;
        ptr2 = ptr2.next;

    }
    ptr1.next = ptr2;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be `2 While` loop to pick one element and check if the `element` exists in the `Linked List`. Following code may help you understand better.

```
LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr1=head;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> ptr2=head.next;
        if(head==null)
            return null;
        if(head.next==null)
            return head;

        while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1.next != NULL) // pick 1 element at time
        { 
            ptr2 = ptr1; 
            while (ptr2.next != NULL) 
            { 
                if (ptr1.data == ptr2.next.data) // check if the element exits in LinkedList or not
                { 
                    dup = ptr2.next; 
                    ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next; 

                } 
                else 
                    ptr2 = ptr2.next; 
            } 
            ptr1 = ptr1.next; 
        } 
        return head;
```

Comment: This code `ptr1.data == ptr2.next->data`  does not appear to be Java :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thanks for pointing out the error. It was done in C++

Answer (score 0):

If I just read your title you can remove duplicates from `LinkedList` by iterate over , store value in a `Set` and check for duplicates via the `Set` if contains return `true` call remove on the integrator.

```java
Iterator iter = list.iterator();
Set set = new HashSet();
while (iter.hasNext())
 {

  Object obj = iter.next();
  if(set.contains(obj))){
        iter.remove();
  }else{
        set.add(obj);
      }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer i forgot to mention that there was a requirement of O(1) space complexity your answer would be the best otherwise though

Answer (score 0):

remove duplicate

```
list.stream().distinct().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There's one minor moment:OP's list is not implementing `<List>` from Collections Framework and does not have stream() as such  ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Answer (score 0):

Without using extra space, just iterating through the linkedlist once per node can server the purpose

```
public void removeDupsFromLinkedList(Node head)
    {
        LinkedListImpl linkedListImpl = new LinkedListImpl();
        if(head==null)
            return;
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            Node traverseNode = temp;
            while(traverseNode!=null)
            {
                if(traverseNode.value==temp.value && traverseNode!=temp)
                    linkedListImpl.deleteNode(traverseNode);
                traverseNode=traverseNode.next;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
```